# Creating prestashop multistore

Tags: prestashop, multistore

I have one domain and two subdomains, eg: domain.com with yes.domain.com and no.domain.com
I want to have two stores with different categories, eg: electronic in yes.domain.com and fashion in no.domain.com
On my domain (domain.com) I want to create custom landing page containing two images that linking to yes.domain.com and no.domain.com and some menus that linking to static pages.

How to create multistore like that using prestashop?
Do i have to install prestashop in yes.domain.com and no.domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily manage your 2 shops with single install of Prestashop.
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Managing+Multiple+Shops#ManagingMultipleShops-Themultistoreinterface

Create simple index.html on your domain.com

Comment: Hmm, i have created simple main page using bootstrap. Then i install prestashop on yes.domain.com, so i created multistore. But it will create second store as yes.domain.com/no.  
How to create second store as no.domain.com if i install prestashop on yes.domain.com